Testing monotonicity for functions of the form $f :\{0,1,2\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$
I am looking for a property testing algorithem for testing mononicity for functions of the form $f :\{0,1,2\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ which means that whenever $x \le y$ then $f(x) \le f(y)$ and by $x \le y$ i mean that $x=x_1x_2\dots x_n \le y=y_1y_2\dots y_n$ iff $x_i \le y_i$ for every $i \in [n]$.
i am familiar only with property testing monotnicity with boolean functions ( functions of the form $f :\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where the algorithem samples $\mathcal{O}(\frac{m}{\epsilon})$ edges from the boolean hypercube of dimension n and returns no if one of them was non monotone with respect to $f$ ( the boolean hypercube is an undirected graph whose verticies are the vectors of the set $\{0,1\}^n$ and where every two verticies $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ that differ by only one coordinate are connected by an edge.furthermore an edge $xy$ is non monotone with respect to $f$ if $x \le y$ and $ f(x) \gt f(y)$ ).  is there any way to generilize the problem from functions  $f :\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ to  $f :\{0,1,2\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ ? or maybe another simpler method that could work, or any hint or reference that may help.

See, e.g., https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v010a017/ ("monotonicity testing over the hypergrid"). By the way, for the hypercube there is a $\sqrt{n}$-query tester (can do better than linear in $n$).

@ClementC. thanks for the reference.
